# Running GLFW in Docker

Tags: docker, x-server, opengl, xvfb

I have a simple program written in Go that opens a blank window using GLFW. I'd like to automatically run tests, therefore I have been trying to get GLFW running in docker. So far I've already managed to get xvfb running.

My problem is that I get an error `GLX extension not found` when calling `glfwInit`. Also, running `glxinfo` yields this error `couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig`. From what I can find online this is because GLFW cannot find the GPU (because there is none).

Is there still a library I need to install or can I configure something differently *(e.g. running GLFW in headless mode)* to prevent this error?

Here is a shortened version of my Dockerfile (removed Go specific stuff):

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates wget
RUN wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub
RUN wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.28-r0/glibc-2.28-r0.apk
RUN apk add glibc-2.28-r0.apk

RUN apk update
RUN apk add gcc
RUN apk add mesa-dev
RUN apk add libx11-dev
RUN apk add libc-dev
RUN apk add libx11-dev
RUN apk add libxcursor-dev
RUN apk add libxi-dev
RUN apk add libxinerama-dev
RUN apk add libxrandr-dev
RUN apk add xorg-server
RUN apk add xvfb
RUN apk add coreutils
RUN apk add mesa
RUN apk add mesa-gl
RUN apk add mesa-demos
RUN apk add xvfb-run --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/ --allow-untrusted
RUN apk add mesa-osmesa

#if you are unfamiliar with docker, this is the command that gets run when starting the container.
ENTRYPOINT xvfb-run -e /dev/stderr --server-args=':99 -screen 0 640x480x8 +extension GLX +render -noreset -ac' glxinfo | cat
```

Output:

```
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Unsupported high keycode 372 for name <I372> ignored
>                   X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
>                   This warning only shows for the first high keycode.
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
name of display: :99
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

I think the XKEYBOARD warning is not important and can probably be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the `mesa-dri-gallium` package was missing to enable the GLX extension.

The finished Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk update

# Dependencies for GLFW (not required for this example)
RUN apk add \
    build-base \
    libx11-dev \ 
    libxcursor-dev \
    libxrandr-dev \
    libxinerama-dev \
    libxi-dev \
    mesa-dev

# Required to run xvfb-run
RUN apk add mesa-dri-gallium xvfb-run

# virtualgl includes glxinfo
RUN apk add virtualgl --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted

ENTRYPOINT xvfb-run -e /dev/stderr glxinfo | cat
```